# c# eliminate switch requirement

Tags: c#, object, switch-statement

My case value text is always be equals to the relevant OSResultStruct in the code for "The way i have it implemented now and is working".So for example if the case is osedition then the property is OSResultStruct.OSEdition.

Is it possible to do something like the line of code below? If so then i can replace my switch statement with one line of code.

```
lstNewItems[i].sItemValue = OSresult.OSResultStruct."lstNewItems[i].sItemName.ToString().ToUpper()";
```

**The way i have it implimented now and is working**

```
 switch (lstNewItems[i].sItemName)
        {
          case "osedition":
          lstNewItems[i].sItemValue = OSresult.OSResultStruct.OSEdition;
          break;
          case "osbuild":
          lstNewItems[i].sItemValue = OSresult.OSResultStruct.OSBuild;
          break;
          case "osmajor":    
          //.....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Reflection:-

```
OSresult.OSResultStruct.GetType().GetProperty(lstNewItems[i].sItemName,BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(OSresult.OSResultStruct, null)
```

For a more generic approach:-

Define an extension class:-

```
public static class ClassExtensions
    {
        public static TRes GetPublicPropertyValue<T,TRes>(this T queryObject, string propertyMatch) 
            where T : class,new()
            where TRes : new()

        {
            return (TRes)typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyMatch, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(queryObject, null);
        }
    }
```

Use it for any instantiable type as follows:-

```
OSresult.OSResultStruct.GetPublicPropertyValue<yourtype,yourreturntype>(attribName);
```

Comment: when i did this 
                            lstNewItems[i].sItemValue = OSresult.OSResultStruct.GetType().GetProperty(lstNewItems[i].sItemName).GetValue(OSresult.OSResultStruct, null).ToString();
i got the error Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Note i added the method .tostring()

Comment: how do i ignorecase as alexi recommended above?

Comment: Use Binding Flag and see GetProperty(lstNewItems[i].sItemName, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.IgnoreCase)

Comment: still the same (Object reference....." error - the line now is                             lstNewItems[i].sItemValue = OSresult.OSResultStruct.GetType().GetProperty(lstNewItems[i].sItemName, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.IgnoreCase).GetValue(OSresult.OSResultStruct, null).ToString().ToLower();

Comment: No you need to add other flags too since it will replace the default binding flags. Please see my answer. I have updated it, assuming your property is public..If not you can use the other flag.

Comment: Glad it works. :) I have updated with a more generic way of doing it. In your case you can use object as the return type since the type you are looking for is a string...

Answer (score 4):

Not going to be shorter but... You may write and extension methiod and attribute. Then add that attribute to each enum member and resolved it by a string from the attribute. This will make it one line and reusable.

Some code for clarification -- as I said it was not going to be short :)

```
private static readonly Dictionary<DriveTrain, DriveTrainKind> DriveTrainKindMap = 
    Enums.GetValues<DriveTrain>().ToDictionary(d => d, d => d.GetDriveTrainKind());

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class DriveTrainKindAttribute : Attribute
{
    public DriveTrainKindAttribute(DriveTrainKind kind)
    {
        Kind = kind;
    }

    public DriveTrainKind Kind { get; private set; }
}

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static DriveTrainKind GetDriveTrainKind(this DriveTrain value)
    {
        var fieldInfo = typeof(DriveTrain).GetField(value.ToString());
        var attributes = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DriveTrainKindAttribute), false)
                                  .Cast<DriveTrainKindAttribute>();
        return attributes.Select(a => a.Kind).SingleOrDefault();
    }
}

public enum DriveTrainKind : byte
{
    ConventionalOrHybrid = 0,
    PluginHybrid = 1,
    BatteryElectric = 2,
}

public enum DriveTrain : short 
{
    [Description("konv_otto"), DriveTrainKind(DriveTrainKind.ConventionalOrHybrid)]
    ConventionalGasoline = 0,

    [Description("konv_diesel"), DriveTrainKind(DriveTrainKind.ConventionalOrHybrid)]
    ConventionalDiesel = 1,
    ...
}
```

Comment: While reflection is clever it cannot be compile time checked by the compiler (and that's why you're using a compiled language, right?). Using extension methods with attributes is compile time checked. If the number of attributes is a large number, be pragmatic and use reflection but make sure to unit test all possible values.

Comment: @cfeduke That's correct. Although correctness of strings in that switch is also not compile time checkable. So both things lack the same IMO. This is one of the cool features I am missing in C# from Java - enums.

Comment: I prefer this too - reflection should be used sparingly

Comment: @Schultz9999 yeah, guess there's no good way around magical strings - and yes on Java enums, I'm a Java transplant from C# and love the [new] enum implementation (use it all the time)

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection - get property accessor ([Type.GetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek55ae84.aspx) ) by name (you'll need to specify [IgnoreCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) when getting one as your names seem to be all lower case) and than [GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385.aspx) of property using accessor.